# SQL statement - most

Tags: sql

For the following database schema:

```
Medication-MedicationID, BrandName, GenericName
```

What would be the SQL statement to retrieve the most prescribed generic medication name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this to get the item with the most prescriptions:

```
select max(GenericCount)
from
(
    select count(*) GenericCount, GenericName
    from yourtable
    group by GenericName
) x
```

If you want to see the number each one is prescribed, then use:

```
    select count(*) GenericCount, GenericName
    from yourtable
    group by GenericName
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am new at this, so I apologize if this is a stupid question but where did GenericCount come from?

Comment: It is the alias that I gave to the field `count(*)`.

Comment: what does that `x` means in the last?

Comment: @Talha `x` is an alias for the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(COUNT(GenericName)), GenericName FROM MedicationTable GROUP BY GenericName
```

Where the table is named `MedicationTable`

Comment: Thank you, I am new at this, and have been searching for 2 hours.